# What is Vout in this diagram?

Tags: capacitor, kirchhoffs-laws

I am trying to figure out how I can find Vout in this diagram I am sharing right now. I tried kirchoff but it does not seem helpful or possible to work with and I am assuming Vin is just an arbitrary AC signal coming in(just for now we can assume it is a sinusodial signal). I am aware that the capacitor blocks DC current and let Vin to be coupled to Vout but what I do not understand is how alike Vin and Vout are. What I mean is if Vout is like Vin in shape but with offset or Vout has totally different shape with respect to Vin. Please help me get through this. Whenever I see a capacitor, I am paralyzed because I cannot guess its effect on output voltage like this scenario.

[image: the scenario]

Comment: If it is AC steady state then replace the capacitor with -jXc.

Comment: If C is transparent to Vin, then Vout = Vin + DC offset based on R1/R2.

Comment: In general, capacitors and resistors are linear devices.  Thus if the input is a sine wave, the output will also be a sine wave although its amplitude and phase may be different.

Comment: It depends on impedance of Cap vs R at input frequency for attenuation and slew rate. http://tinyurl.com/yagsqthz does that help?

Comment: with some attenuation http://tinyurl.com/y7o3y238

Comment: $$\begin{align*}\frac{V_\text{a}}{R_1}+\frac{V_\text{a}}{R_2}+C\,\frac{\text{d}\,V_\text{a}}{\text{d}\,t}&=\frac{10\:\text{V}}{R_1}+\frac{0\:\text{V}}{R_2}+C\,\frac{\text{d}\,V_\text{in}}{\text{d}\,t}\\\frac{\text{d}\,V_\text{a}}{\text{d}\,t}+\frac1{C}\left(\frac1{R_1}+\frac1{R_2}\right)V_\text{a}&=\frac{\text{d}\,V_\text{in}}{\text{d}\,t}+\frac{10\:\text{V}}{R_1}\end{align*}$$

Comment: Without knowing exactly what the input signals are, everything is guesswork. If this is a homework question, there must be more detail than you've revealed here. We are not mind readers.

Answer (score 2):

R1 and R2 from a potential divider between two fixed potentials, and create a DC operating point (average value of \$V_{OUT}\$) calculated as:

$$ V_{OUT(DC)} = 10V \times \frac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2} $$

The capacitor doesn't actually influence this DC average, and thus doesn't figure in this equation. That's because of the famous "DC blocking" behaviour of capacitors. If all signals were steady, unchanging, then the capacitor would charge up over time, eventually to a voltage exactly spanning the difference between whatever potentials would be present on either side, as if the capacitor weren't even there.

In fact, that's how DC operating point analysis is performed, by removing capacitors (and replacing inductor with short circuits), so that all you are left with is non-reactive elements. In that state, all DC potentials in the circuit would instantly settle to their long-term values, defining what voltages capacitors will ultimately charge to, and what currents inductors would ultimately pass in quiescent conditions.

Once this "quiescent" state of \$V_{OUT}\$ is known, it's safe to convert R1 and R2, and the voltage sources at either end of them, into a Thevenin equivalent, which consists of a single voltage source, and a single resistance:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4gRtw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The value of the voltage source \$V_{TH}\$ is whaveter you calculated above for \$V_{OUT(DC)}\$, and the resistance \$R_{TH}\$ is the parallel combination of R1 and R2.

From there, your circuit has simplified to:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbWZk2.png)</sup>

Now analysis should be a lot simpler. Just remember that the average value of \$V_{OUT}\$ will be \$V_{TH}\$, and any signal there will be offset by that average. Otherwise the circuit may be treated is if this were a simple RC high-pass filter.

Answer (score 0):

In case you just need value then you can try simulator like multisim to see waveform.

Simulator will help you to get result without physically implementing the circuit and this will save your time as well.

Comment: Welcome to EE-SE and good idea. Perhaps it is helpful to the OP if you included an example simulation to illustrate the waveform (and phase shift), since he wants the expression but also the "shape".